# break up of single table into two tables

Tags: sql, database, datatable, database-normalization

consider a table dbo.order having 50 columns. would it be a good way to break its 30 fields into another table bill_invoice? details are as under:

### table ( order)

id(pk);order_id;order_amont;...up to 20 fields

### table ( bill_invoice )

id(pk); order_id(fk from dbo.order table); field_1; field_2 .... upto field_30

.... and their details tables are:

### table (bill_detail_01)

id(pk); bill_invoice_id ( fk from dbo.bill_invoice ); field_1, field2... upto field_10

### table (bill_detail_02)

id(pk); bill_invoice_id ( fk from dbo.bill_invoice ); field_1, field2... upto field_10

### table (bill_detail_03)

id(pk); bill_invoice_id ( fk from dbo.bill_invoice ); field_1, field2... upto field_10

.
.
.
.

If we have a table dbo.[order] having 50 fields, then would it be heavy while insertion 50 fields records?

then should we break this main dbo.[order] fields into another table ( bill_invoice )? as mentioned above?

would it be the good approach to reduce insertion load? or should we prefer normalization to use only dbo.[order] with 50 fields?

Comment: Ken Lee has answered me and he got my point why I asked such question regarding managing data and I am satisfying with his reply "If you split the data into different tables, then say if you want to delete one record, you will need to delete all the "linked" records in all the "split" tables. The workload will even be heavier."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a modern database system cannot handle a data insertion / updating operation of 50 data fields.

If you split the data into different tables, then say if you want to delete one record, you will need to delete all the "linked" records in all the "split" tables. The workload will even be heavier.

On the other hand, normalization will be used if it is necessary. For example if you want to reduce redundancy or similar purposes. But it is not normally related to the data insertion loading problem.

Comment: Unless one order will have many many invoices , otherwise you can store the invoice data (e.g. deposit amount, final payment amount, remarks) of the invoice with the order data record. But of course if an order will have "recurrent" invoices (say an invoice will be issued every month for each order), then you will need to put the invoice data into a separate table